# insert object in an NSMutableArray saved with NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I have an NSMutableArray saved with NSUserDefaults.
This array is my "favourite" items that the user can saves, so when i want to add one item, i need to read the array (from NSuserDefault) and save in the first free position.

I'm using this method to add a value in the NSMutableArray

```
-(IBAction)save{
   NSMutableArray *abc = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"12345"];
   int n = [abc count];
   [abc insertObject:@"aaa" atIndex:n];
   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:abc forKey:@"12345"];
   [defaults synchronize];
   [abc release];
}
```

what's the deal?
That if the user call this method two times, the second time the app crashes with this log:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

why?
and why just the second time?
The first time works fine!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` always returns immutable objects, even if the original object was mutable. It's in the documentation for `objectForKey`:

> The returned object is immutable, even if the value you originally set was mutable.

You will need to create a copy of the returned object before you modify it, using `[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:]`

Probably also best to use the `arrayForKey` method of `NSUserDefaults` if you're retrieving an array. Docs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults

Comment: right! :) `NSMutableArray *bbb = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:abc];` works! thanks!

Comment: @JJSaccolo: A shortcut you can take is `NSMutableArray *bbb = [abc mutableCopy];`.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a complete working example:

```
- (void)saveScore:(NSNumber *)score
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray *scoreList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: [defaults objectForKey:@"ScoreList"]];
    [scoreList addObject:score];
    [defaults setObject:scoreList forKey:@"ScoreList"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

First we read in the stored data in a mutable array, update the array, save the new array, and then synchronize the user defaults to permanently record the changes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm guessing you would retrieve it like.. NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; NSMutableArray *array = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"arraySaveData"];
    
    _mutableArray=array;

Answer (score 1):

Another option is:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"12345"] arrayByAddingObject:object] forKey:@"12345"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy Array from an `NSUserDefault` like this way :

```
[YourArray addObjectsFromArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
                  objectForKey:@"NSUSD"]];
```

#### or

```
YourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] 
             initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  
              objectForKey:@"NSUSD"]];
[YourArray addObject: (currentObject)];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you NSMutablepointer points an NSUserDefault object directly. You should first copy NSUserDefault object to an array than process it.

```
NSMutableArray *arr= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"asd",@"dsa",nil];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:arr forKey:@"12345"];
NSMutableArray *abc = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"12345"]];
//[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"12345"];
    int n = [abc count];
    [abc insertObject:@"aaa" atIndex:n];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:abc forKey:@"12345"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    [abc release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix:

```
_retrivedArray = [_mutableArray mutableCopy];
```