# Save NSMutableArray into NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I'm making an app where you can keep track of the money you have. I wanted to present a log of the money added so I needed an NSMutableArray to store that information.

So what I want to know is how to store an NSMutableArray into NSUserDefaults so that I can add information to it at **anytime**. I've seen many questions here, but they don't help, because most of them don't talk about NSUserDefaults giving **non** mutable arrays.

To sum everything up, I need to dynamically add information to my array every time a method is called (saving an integer-or NSNumber) to then present it as an UITableView

Comment: If you've seen other answers what part are you getting stuck on? `NSUserDefaults` will give you an immutable array. To make it mutable just call 'mutableCopy` on the array

Comment: possible duplicate of [insert object in an NSMutableArray saved with NSUserDefaults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346395/insert-object-in-an-nsmutablearray-saved-with-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 0):

Just fetch your (immutable) array from the defaults, then initialize the mutable array instance you're working with in your app from that using [`NSObjects`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s `mutableCopy` method:

```
  NSMutableArray *array = [arrayFromDefaults mutableCopy];
```

Since `NSArray` implements the [`NSMutableCopying`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSMutableCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSMutableCopying) protocol it '*knows*' what its mutable counterpart is.